# How do I make the "Add" button on a navigation bar do something?

Tags: ios, xcode

So I've taken a few years off since my last iPhone programming adventure, and I've apparently forgotten most of what I learned last time. Plus XCode looks totally different, so I'm having to re-learn that as well.

I've used the Storyboard feature to lay out the basic UI of my next project. The main screen is embedded in a Navigation controller, and I have four buttons on the main screen. Pressing any button causes a sub-view to be loaded; I haven't gotten past the sub-views yet. So, in summary, what I have right now is a main/home screen, plus four separate sub-views, each of which is accessed by tapping a button on the main/home screen. This all works peachy so far.

So. On my first sub-view - call it the "People" screen - I have a bar button item with the "Add" function ([+]) on it. What I'm trying to do is get an Action Sheet to appear when the add button is tapped. Unfortunately, no amount of control-dragging from this button to any location in any .h/.m file in my project will produce the little pop-up where I can set up an action/outlet.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What file are you trying to drag to? You can't drag to your implementation of your main view controller from one of the sub view controllers. You'll have to declare new subclasses for them, set their classes to the new subclasses you declared and then drag there.

Comment: I was trying to keep this as simple as possible; I find it's very easy to get lost working in Xcode. So, to start with, I didn't have any new subclasses. That obviously didn't work. Next, I added a new subclass of UIViewController and set my home/main screen to that ("MainViewController"). Still no dice. Next, I added another subclass ("PeopleViewController"), and it doesn't even show up in the Class Type drop-down in the Inspector. So I have no idea what's going on there.

Comment: Is it correctly added to your target? You might have to clean and rebuild your project or simply type in your class name.

Answer (score 9):

```
addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addItem:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

Then you have to add a void method called "addItem", in which you have to define what do you want the Add button to do(in your case an actionsheet).